# Returning an arrow function to a component

Tags: reactjs

I have the arrow function below and I want to be able to return everything here to a component.
How do I return everything? Is it possible to use an export with this? The code below resides in 
a js file.

```
const myTester = props => {
  [
    {
      title: props.intl.formatMessage({
        id: "ren_past_due"
      }),
      icon: (
        <EventBusy
          color="#cc2444"
          style={style}
          className="icon-box-icon-image material-icons"
        />
      ),
      color: "#C60C30",
      expiresBefore: today()
    },
    {
      title: props.intl.formatMessage({
        id: "ren_zerotothree_months"
      }),
      icon: (
        <Today
          color="#f2b826"
          style={style}
          className="icon-box-icon-image material-icons"
        />
      ),
      color: "#F0AB00",
      expiresAfter: today(),
      expiresBefore: today().add(3, "months")
    }
  ].map(item => {
    if (item.expiresBefore) {
      item.expiresBefore = item.expiresBefore.format("Y-MM-DD");
    }
    if (item.expiresAfter) {
      item.expiresAfter = item.expiresAfter.format("Y-MM-DD");
    }
    return item;
  });
};
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you expect to use this data once it's returned?

Comment: Once returned title, icon and color will be placed on some controls  that looks like square for display and expiresAfter/expiresBefore will be used as parameters to a web service.

Comment: That wouldn't return anything. Does that function really work? I think the curlies must be parentheses.

Comment: Which curlies are you referring to please?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `return` in front of `[` in line #2.

Shorthand to return arrays `() => ([1, 2, 3]);`.

Shorthand to return object `() => ({ name: 'shorthand' });`.

Comment: I think user2320476 want's to have whole function some where else then just what it calculates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you are using this 'javascript' file.

If wanted to use like like a NPM module then just simply do following:

```
module.exports = myTester;
```

When importing this file you will get this function

```
const test = require('./myTester.js');
// test is now test(props);
```

On front-end on older ways before `rectJs` and `import` this would had just worked by calling function `myTester(props)` and importing file via script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myTester.js"></script>
```

With `react` or new ways now it's

```
import myTester from 'myTester'
```